# Applying transpositions and calculating the order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Could someone please show me how to multiply out transpositions and find their order?

For instance,

say $g,h \in S_4$ where $S$ is the group of permutations,

take for example, $g = (13)$ and $h = (123)$

then $o(g) = 2$ as $g^2 = e$ and $o(h) = 3$ as $h^3 = e$, How would I go about calculating $gh = (13)(123)$? My attempt was to apply $(123)$ first then $(13)$ so I receive an answer of $(12)$ which has an order of $2$, so $o(gh) = 2$, however wolframalpha gives an answer of $(23)$ - where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram is multiplying left to right while you are multiplying right to left. Hence two different answers. Applying $(123)$ first yields the answer that you have so you aren't going wrong.

Comment: Why is there two different ways to apply the permutation?

Comment: It comes down to notation/convention. When we do function composition, we write $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ and we work from the inside out, which corresponds to right-to-left. We typically do the same with permutations.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. I thought this was convention everywhere - Anyway, thank you!